# Can I make a full export of a corrupted database?

Tags: oracle

I have a datafile with a corrupted block. Unfortunately I don't have backup to repair with RMAN (BAD strategy, first the strategy delete the old backup and after make a new backup) Because this new corruption I can't make a new backup with RMAN..

What happen if I make a full export of the database? the export will fail as well? Can I filter for don't make the export of the data in that block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the full scan on that table with a corrupt block will fail, but you can make the scans skip the corrupt blocks of an object:

[DBMS_REPAIR.SKIP_CORRUPT_BLOCKS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_REPAIR.html#GUID-F86D3785-6305-4429-9DC4-082BF530312C)

> This procedure enables or disables the skipping of corrupt blocks
>   during index and table scans of the specified object.

```
DBMS_REPAIR.SKIP_CORRUPT_BLOCKS (
   schema_name  IN VARCHAR2,
   object_name  IN VARCHAR2,
   object_type  IN BINARY_INTEGER DEFAULT TABLE_OBJECT,
   flags        IN BINARY_INTEGER DEFAULT SKIP_FLAG);
```

In RMAN you can create a backup with corrupt blocks by specifying the allowed maximum amount of corrupt blocks:

[SET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/SET.html#GUID-BC501B5C-4CD0-485D-AA18-27E2894024C3)

> MAXCORRUPT FOR DATAFILE datafileSpec TO integer
>
> Sets a limit on the number of previously undetected block corruptions
>   that the database permits in a specified data file or group of data
>   files. The default limit is zero, meaning that RMAN tolerates no
>   corrupt blocks.
>
> The SET MAXCORRUPT command specifies the total number of physical and
>   logical corruptions permitted in a data file during a backup job. If
>   the sum of physical and logical corruptions detected for a data file
>   is no more than its MAXCORRUPT setting, then the BACKUP command
>   completes. If more than MAXCORRUPT corrupt blocks exist, then RMAN
>   terminates without creating output files.

But you should just fix the object with the corrupt block instead of ignoring it.

Comment: What is the best alternative to fix it without any backup in this moment?

Comment: @SolaireofAstora Depends on the type of corruption. I assumed the worst: data in a table. In that case you use the above then create a copy of that table with CTAS (with the corrupt data missing of course), or expdp/impdp. If the corrupt block belongs to an index, you can just rebuild the index. If the corrupt block does not belong to any segment, you can just overwrite that area by creating a big enough dummy table. You can map the corrupt block to a segment with `DBA_EXTENTS`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!